# How to merge some fields of second array into first array after comparing the values of keys common in both arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value, array-merge

My question sounds bit confusing but actually it's simple. Let me describe you the scenario first. I've two arrays viz. `$grid_data` and `$sent_data`. Both the arrays generate dynamically depending on the user input. So for instance I'm printing below the contents of both of these arrays:

```
$grid_data = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [newsletter_id] => 1
                [newsletter_name] => Eywa Solutions
                [newsletter_subject] => Holi Wishes
                [newsletter_email_body] => Happy Holi to all the friends
                [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
                [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
                [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
                [newsletter_status] => 2
                [newsletter_schedule] => 0
                [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 17 2014, 16:21 pm
                [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [newsletter_id] => 2
                [newsletter_name] => Akshay Nikte
                [newsletter_subject] => The Don
                [newsletter_email_body] => How are yoy Nikte Saheb?
                [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
                [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
                [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
                [newsletter_status] => 2
                [newsletter_schedule] => 0
                [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 18 2014, 06:52 am
                [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
            )

    )

$sent_data = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [newsletter_id] => 1
                    [newsletter_sent_count] => 5
                    [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121193
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [newsletter_id] => 2
                    [newsletter_sent_count] => 7
                    [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121227
                )

        )
```

Now what I want to achieve is compare the values of key `[newsletter_id]` from both of the above arrays with each other. If match is found append the key-value pairs([newsletter_sent_count], [newsletter_sent_date]) to the respective array from `$grid_data` array. If match is not found then insert blank values for those keys([newsletter_sent_count], [newsletter_sent_date]). In above case the finally generated `$grid _data` should look like below:

```
$grid_data = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [newsletter_id] => 1
                [newsletter_name] => Eywa Solutions
                [newsletter_subject] => Holi Wishes
                [newsletter_email_body] => Happy Holi to all the friends
                [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
                [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
                [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
                [newsletter_status] => 2
                [newsletter_schedule] => 0
                [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 17 2014, 16:21 pm
                [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
                [newsletter_sent_count] => 5
                [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121193
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [newsletter_id] => 2
                [newsletter_name] => Akshay Nikte
                [newsletter_subject] => The Don
                [newsletter_email_body] => How are yoy Nikte Saheb?
                [newsletter_call_to_action_status] => 0
                [newsletter_call_to_action_text] => 
                [newsletter_call_to_action_link] => 
                [newsletter_status] => 2
                [newsletter_schedule] => 0
                [newsletter_created_date] => Mar 18 2014, 06:52 am
                [newsletter_updated_date] => 0
                [newsletter_sent_count] => 7
                [newsletter_sent_date] => 1395121227
            )

    )
```

I want to do this in an most optimum way. I tried using array_merge() to achieve this but I was not succeed in my attempt. So can anyone from the pool of talent help me in this regard please? Thanks in advance. If you need any further information I can provide you the same.
The attempt made by me is as follows:

```
$arr_length = count($grid_data);


for($i=0; $i < $arr_length; $i++) {
  $track =0;
  foreach($sent_data as $value) {
    if($value['newsletter_id'] === $grid_data[$i]['newsletter_id'] ) {
      array_merge($grid_data[$i], $value);
      $track=1;
    }  
  }
  if($track === 0) {
    //insert blank value here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert `$sent_data` into an associative array:

```
$sent_assoc = array();
foreach ($sent_data as $el) {
    $sent_assoc[$el['newsletter_id']] = $el;
}
```

Then do the merging:

```
$default_sent = array('newsletter_sent_count' => null, 'newsletter_sent_date' => null);
foreach ($grid_data as &$el) {
    $id = $el['newsletter_id'];
    $sent = isset($sent_assoc[$id]) ? $sent_assoc[$id] : $default_sent;
    $el = array_merge($el, $sent);
}
```

The reference `&$el` is used so that the assignment updates the original array.

Without the reference the second loop looks like:

```
foreach ($grid_data as $i => $el) {
    $id = $el['newsletter_id'];
    $sent = isset($sent_assoc[$id]) ? $sent_assoc[$id] : $default_sent;
    $grid_data[$i] = array_merge($el, $sent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's not working. Printing blank page. Can you please simplify your code?

Comment: There was an extra parenthesis in the `$found =` line, I've fixed it.

Comment: How much simpler can it get?

Comment: @Barmer:Let me show you the try I've made. Though it's not working for me but you can realize the way I want a simple solution in. For it please see my question. I've updated it with my attempt.

Comment: `array_merge` returns a new array with the combined data, it doesn't modify the array in place. You need to assign it back into `$grid_data`. Your nested loop method is inefficient because it requires N*M comparisons. You should at least put a `break` in the inner loop when it finds a match.

Comment: :Yeah, your this trick worked perfectly for me. But could you please try to make it simpler without using reference. It would be of great help for me. Thanks for your immense help.

Comment: OK, I've added a version without the reference. I don't see how that makes it simpler, it just makes it more verbose.